# java best way to declare variables with main method

Tags: java, string

Hi I was just wondering what the best way to declare a variable in java was:

with static variables declared outside the method:

```
    public class Copy {

   public static Scanner scanInput   =   new Scanner(System.in);
   public static String captureString;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Scanner scanInput   =   new Scanner(System.in);
        //String captureString;

        System.out.println("Please enter some words..");
        captureString   =   scanInput.nextLine();

        System.out.println("You entered: " + captureString);

    }

}
```

or with variables inside the main method:

```
    public class Copy {

   //public static Scanner scanInput   =   new Scanner(System.in);
   //public static String captureString;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scanInput   =   new Scanner(System.in);
        String captureString;

        System.out.println("Please enter some words..");
        captureString   =   scanInput.nextLine();

        System.out.println("You entered: " + captureString);

    }

}
```

Which is the preferred way of declaring variables in this case?

Comment: You are only using them inside the `main` method, so declare them there. In general, declare variables in the tightest scope that you can. This keeps your code cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Declare the variables inside the method! This is not just my opinion, that is the idiomatic answer. While the other will give you functioning code, it pollutes the static namespace for no purpose. If they were constants (and used in multiple classes by design), then I might give you a different answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you can declare the variables inside `main`, then do so.  But you can't if you will be calling other methods in the same class and those methods need to access the same variables (and it's too unwieldy to pass them all around as parameters).  In that case, my preference is to declare them as *non-static* `private` members of the class, and then have `main` create an instance of the class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Copy().doMain(args);
}

public void doMain(String[] args) {        // not static!
    // put your interesting stuff here
}
```

(You don't have to pass `args` if you're not going to use them.)

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If all your code is just in the main method, then declare the variables in the method. However, if other methods or classes need access to them, then they need to be declared globally. In this case it is better to make the fields local instead of global.

P.S. If you want your variables to not be static you could always create an instance of the class.

```
 public class Copy {

   public Scanner scanInput   =   new Scanner(System.in);
   public String captureString;

    public static void main(String[] args){
       new Copy();
    }
    public Copy()
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter some words..");
        captureString   =   scanInput.nextLine();

        System.out.println("You entered: " + captureString);
    }


}
```

This way you will waste memory creating static fields.